# How to avoid a child grid to shrink when parent is a flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Here's a Codepen with my issue: https://codepen.io/Maslow/pen/eYZKjNG?editors=1100

My parent div is a flexbox with `justify-content: space-between`. The second child on the right is a grid. It has plenty of space but it's shrinking on a single column and I don't understand. I'd like it to take up the available space until it has to wrap and only then create a second row.

Do you know how to that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Seing the downvotes I guess I asked the question badly. Anyway here's how I managed to do it.

I used `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 20px);` on the grid then set a `flex: 1` on both children.

Hopefully this helps someone